# 'Specifies the beach sand' why possessive not used

Tags: pronunciation, compounds

I was just reading a book and came across the following line:

> ***on the beach*** specifies beach sand,

and now I'm wondering why the noun isn't used in its possessive form: beach's?

how would 'beach's' be pronounced?

---

**Source:**

> The difference between BY and ON and between BY and AT in the three examples above is that *by the beach* suggests *any* location *near*, *close to*, *on*, or *at* the beach; ***on the beach specifies the beach sand***, *and at the beach* indicates the specific area ranging from the beach sidewalk (and perhaps a little further) to the wet sand that borders the see water (thus, we can infer that BY is more closely related to At than to ON)

Comment: Could you please quote the entire sentence?

Comment: @CowperKettle I just updated the post with a full sentence

Comment: I think it is just a compound noun following this pattern: **Noun+Noun**.

Comment: The Saxon genitive is pronounced /əz/.

Comment: In this sentence, 'beach' acts as an adjective and 'sand' is the noun it modifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Beach sand** is a noun+noun [compound noun](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/compound_noun) meaning sand from a beach, any beach, not necessarily the beach you see.

The [pronunciation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/beach) rhymes with **each**.

Some other compound nouns:

- Cat food
- Moose droppings
- Bus stop
- Soup bowl
- Coffee cup

These are not possessives.

Comment: I want to add that it's silly to use a possessive in such cases, for instance: "**The beach's sand**" means that that the sand belongs to the beach, which is quite silly or "**Coffee's cup**" - a cup that belongs to the coffee?. However, it can work with "**Cat's food**" and "**Moose's droppings**"

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "the beach's sand" would mean "the sand on the beach which we are discussing". For example, we might say "The beach's sand was all washed away by the storm."

On the other hand, "beach sand" is a particular kind of sand, the kind usually found on beaches. Here the word "beach" does not refer to any specific beach. It is a noun serving as an adjective which modifies the word "sand".

English nouns can be changed into actual adjectives by adding suffixes, but new adjectives of this type are now seldom formed.

Even when a well-known noun+suffix adjective exists, it is often acceptable to use just the noun instead:

> I see a wooden door.
>   I see a wood door.
>
> I see an oaken door.
>   I see an oak door.
>
> She had a girlish charm.
>   She had girl charm.
>
> He drank from a golden cup.
>   He drank from a gold cup.
>
> We drew cartoonish characters.
>   We drew cartoon characters.
>
> He swung his brazen sword.
>   He swung his brass sword.
>
> They raised their voices in elfin song.
>   They raised their voices in elf song.

In each case above the meaning of the two sentences is the same or very close. (Though -en and -ish can impart shades of meaning which the noun alone lacks.)

Be that as it may, I know of no adjectival form of "beach". That is why you see "beach sand" with "beach" used unchanged as a adjective.